# How to Hide .php Extension from webpages

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am new in php web development, I am trying this codes to hide .php extension from My website URL, through .htaccess file but it can't work and showing "Server Error"

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
</IfModule>
```

Please help me on this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess

Comment: In addition to this being a dupe - a simple google search would have answered this. I find it astounding that people think its easier to post a question here asking for help than it is to type a generic search term into google. http://tinyurl.com/lweo7ge - the first two search results are from this very website.

Answer (score 1):

You would have found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess) if you did even a basic google search.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L, QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

    # Unless directory, remove trailing slash
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
    RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
    RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Will this work? It seems to me that this will just rewrite from the same url entered. I don't see any PHP subbing going on.

Comment: Yes, it will. $1 will take care of extension

Comment: Im not sure I understand. `$1` represents whatever is in the URL. if the URL is `/test` - at what point does the `.php` get appended? Wouldn't it just rewrite from `/test` also? Im not trying to be a a wise guy - I just really like the simplicity and am curious how it works.